# Can't install WoeUSB on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, dependencies, woeusb

I need to install WoeUSB to create a USB stick to install Windows, so I added the repository using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 
sudo apt update
```

and everything is fine until this point.
when i run `sudo apt install woeusb` I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 woeusb : Depends: p7zip-full but it is not installable
          Depends: libwxbase3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg) but it is not installable
          Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I honestly don't know what to do, i looked online and found nothing, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the packager of `woeusb` omitted some dependencies. You could specify them by hand:

```
sudo apt install woeusb p7zip-full libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-0v5
```